# Creating A Worksheet Generator

Tags: html

I hope you are having a great day!

I have an ecommerce website with pdfs and ebooks for sale. We are based on "education" and we have seen a few websites that have worksheet generators. We tried using httrack to see how they made the script but nothing worked. We would love some help in how does it work and are there any tutorials for that type of task. Thanks and have a great day!

Edit: We forgot to say, we want something similar to education.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code useful for you....

code.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Math WorkSheet</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // For: http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=184125

        var NProblems = 25;
        var xvals = [];
        var yvals = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < NProblems; i++) {
            //  xvals.push(i);    yvals.push(i+1);          // limit to problem values to (0,1) ... 25
            xvals.push(i % 10);
            yvals.push((i % 10) + 1); // limit to single digit problems
        }

        function MakeTable(act) {
            var tmp = '';
            var str = '<table border="1" width="80%"><tr>';
            i = 0;
            while (i < NProblems) {
                x = xvals[i];
                y = yvals[i];
                str += '<td align="right">' + x;
                if (act == 'add') {
                    str += '<br>+ ' + y;
                    tmp = x + y;
                }
                if (act == 'sub') {
                    str += '<br>- ' + y;
                    tmp = x - y;
                }
                if (act == 'mul') {
                    str += '<br>* ' + y;
                    tmp = x * y;
                }
                if (act == 'div') {
                    str += '<br>/ ' + y;
                    tmp = (x / y).toFixed(2);
                }
                str += '<br>_____';
                if (document.getElementById('answers').checked) {
                    str += '<br>' + tmp;
                } else {
                    str += '<br>&nbsp;'
                }
                str += '<br>&nbsp;</td>';
                i++;
                if ((i % 5) == 0) {
                    str += '</tr><tr>';
                }
            }
            str += '</tr></table>';
            return str;
        }

        function GenerateWS() {
            var x = 0;
            var y = 0;
            var str = '';
            var str = '';
            var sel = document.getElementById('MathAction').value;
            switch (sel) {
                case 'add':
                    str += MakeTable(sel);
                    break;
                case 'sub':
                    str += MakeTable(sel);
                    break;
                case 'mul':
                    str += MakeTable(sel);
                    break;
                case 'div':
                    str += MakeTable(sel);
                    break;
                default:
                    alert('No choice selected');
                    break;
            }
            document.getElementById('TBL').innerHTML = str;
        }

        function randOrd() {
            return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5);
        }

        function NewSet() {
            xvals.sort(randOrd);
            yvals.sort(randOrd);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="MathAction">
        <option value="add">Addition</option>
        <option value="sub">Subtraction</option>
        <option value="mul">Multiplication</option>
        <option value="div">Division</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="NewSet()">New worksheet</button>
    <input type="checkbox" id="answers">Show Answers
    <button onclick="GenerateWS()">Generate Worksheet</button>
    <div id="TBL"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
But I need to be more specific. I would like the code or something similar to these generators: https://www.education.com/worksheet-generator/reading/